# Angular: Using ngShow and Hide to remove spinner if no data returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the below HTML that displays a spinner until a list of tags displays for an application. However, the spinner continues if there are no events that exist either.

I'd like the spinner to disappear and the input just be blank or return a message to the user that there are no tags for this app. Not sure how to do that whilst keeping the code clean!

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="noun === 'Tag'">
  <div class="spinner" ng-hide="loadedTags()">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="loadedTags()">
    <select ol-filter-select="tags" ng-model="tagName">
      <option ng-value="name" ng-repeat="name in tagNames()" ng-bind="name"   ng-selected="tagName === name">
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.loadedTags = function() {
  return !_.isEmpty($scope.tags);
};
```

View:

Spinner keeps spinning if there's no tags...

[image]

Comment: Please format the HTML section. Looks like there is a missing closing div </div>

Comment: what check length your data and do decision

Comment: what does $scope.tags look like? is lodash being included properly? I would say the improper HTML that Rathish pointed out would be the culprit.

Comment: Please create a plnkr/jsfiddle so we can see what the issue is. It is not clear if you are using lodash or underscore. Also not clear what the value of $scope.tags is when there are no tags.

Comment: Are you using $http to load the tags?

Comment: Yes I am using $http.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to show more of the code that is actually loading the tags.  Are you loading the tags from the server via $http.get or something similar?  If so, then typically the way this would be done is to have a boolean scope variable that specifically represents the fact that loading is currently in progress.  That variable would control whether the spinner is visible.  For example, I have common code that looks like this:

Constructor for Angular controller:

```
$scope.loadingInProgress = true;

$http.get(myUrl)
.then(function(result) { 
    // My success function
    $scope.tags = result.data; 
    $scope.loadingInProgress = false;
},
function() { 
    // My failure function
    $scope.loadingInProgress = false; 
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="spinner" ng-show="loadingInProgress">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
  </div>
```

It seems like you're trying to avoid an extra scope variable to represent the loading state, so you're trying to calculate the loading state based on the results of the load.  But that's not really reliable.  The results of the load could be anything, and doesn't really indicate whether loading is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

The above should work, assuming you're using underscore.js. You're sure the controller is in the same scope as that bit of html?

Maybe try the following:

```
$scope.loadedTags = function() {
  return $scope.tags.length > 0;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

loadedTags() will be evaluated only on digest cycle, not every time $scope.tags is changed.
Instead, create variable $scope.isVisible watch on $scope.tags to update isVisible state.
Then, your ng-show=isVisible.

Comment: nope, `ng-hide` will parse the expression on every digest cycle, not only once.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I meant once on digest. updated.

Comment: Still wrong, your watch will also be executed on each digest cycle. In fact, `ng-hide` creates a watcher exactly like the one you suggest to add manually.

Comment: ng-hide creates watcher on object returned from loadedTags(), that is why your own scope variable need instead of function call. If there is watch on object tags, where you will update the state of isVisible - you are getting the behavior requested.